using libffmpeg to set loop on a resized gif
I'm using libffmpeg and during the process of resizing a gif, I use the following:
av_opt_set_int(outputFormatContext, "loop", 0, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);

But the final result doesn't loop. Any ideas?

Questions about the C interface of FFmpeg better be asked in Stack Overflow site. There might be a muxer option for setting the loop configuratrion. For increasing the chance of getting an answer, I recommend you to post a code sample that can be built and executed (it's going to be a lot of code...)

The loop option is not an libavformat option but an FFmpeg CLI option, therefore nothing library users can use.
You can check how the CLI implements this by checking where the loop variable is used in the code, for example here:
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/fftools/ffmpeg_demux.c#L726
(Also there is no such thing as libffmpeg in upstream FFmpeg.)
